# Identifying issue in retrieving href from Google Scholar

Tags: python, xpath, href, google-scholar

Having trouble scraping links and article names from google scholar. I'm unsure if the issue is with my code or the xpath that I'm using to retrieve the data – or possibly both?

I've already spent the past few hours trying to debug/consulting other stackoverflow queries but to no success.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapyproj.items import ScrapyProjItem

class scholarScrape(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "scholarScraper"
    allowed_domains = "scholar.google.com"
    start_urls=["https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&oe=ASCII&as_sdt=0%2C44&q=rare+disease+discovery&btnG="]

    def parse(self,response):
        item = ScrapyProjItem()
        item['hyperlink'] = item.xpath("//h3[class=gs_rt]/a/@href").extract()
        item['name'] = item.xpath("//div[@class='gs_rt']/h3").extract()
        yield item
```

The error messages I have been receiving say: "AttributeError: xpath" so I believe that the issue lies with the path that I'm using to try and retrieve the data, but I could also be mistaken?

Comment: The issue is with `scrapyproj.items.ScrapyProjItem` objects: they do not have an `xpath` attribute. Is this an official scrapy class? I think you meant to call `xpath` on `response`.

Comment: Thanks for the "response" – you were right, the issue was resolved after I tried calling `xpath` on `response`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer, as it solved the problem:

The issue is with `scrapyproj.items.ScrapyProjItem` objects: they do not have an `xpath` attribute. Is this an official scrapy class? I think you meant to call `xpath` on `response`:

```
item['hyperlink'] = response.xpath("//h3[class=gs_rt]/a/@href").extract()
item['name'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='gs_rt']/h3").extract()
```

Also, the first path expression might need a set of quotes around the attribute value "gs_rt":

```
item['hyperlink'] = response.xpath("//h3[class='gs_rt']/a/@href").extract()
```

Apart from that, the XPath expressions are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `bs4`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, os

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Container where all articles located
for article_info in soup.select('#gsc_a_b .gsc_a_t'):
  # title CSS selector
  title = article_info.select_one('.gsc_a_at').text
  # Same title CSS selector, except we're trying to get "data-href" attribute
  # Note, it will be relative link, so you need to join it with absolute link after extracting.
  title_link = article_info.select_one('.gsc_a_at')['data-href']
  print(f'Title: {title}\nTitle link: https://scholar.google.com{title_link}\n')

# Part of the output:
'''
Title: Automating Gödel's Ontological Proof of God's Existence with Higher-order Automated Theorem Provers.
Title link: https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ&citation_for_view=m8dFEawAAAAJ:-f6ydRqryjwC
'''
```

Alternatively, you can do the same with [Google Scholar Author Articles API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-articles) from SerpApi.

The main difference is that you don't have to think about finding good proxies, trying to solve CAPTCHA even if you're using `selenium`. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "author_id": "9PepYk8AAAAJ",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for article in results['articles']:
  article_title = article['title']
  article_link = article['link']

# Part of the output:
'''
Title: p-GaN gate HEMTs with tungsten gate metal for high threshold voltage and low gate current
Link: https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=9PepYk8AAAAJ&citation_for_view=9PepYk8AAAAJ:bUkhZ_yRbTwC
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.